# Consequences of a bound on possible counterexamples to Riemann hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

The Riemann hypothesis has many strong consequences in number theory. The question is: would a bound on the number of zeros of Riemann zeta-function in the critical strip with real part not equal 1/2 have significant consequences? For example, what would the statement that a number of such zeros is finite imply?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such bounds are generally called zero-density estimates (for the Riemann zeta function or more general $L$-functions), and they have significant consequences. Chapter 10 of Iwaniec-Kowalski's Analytic number theory is devoted to this topic.

A famous example of such a result and application is Huxley's theorem (Inventiones Mathematicae 15 (1972), 164-170): for $x^{7/12+\epsilon}<h<x$ the number of primes in $[x,x+h]$ is asymptotically $h/\log x$. Other fascinating consequences include connections with the Lindelöf Hypothesis (see e.g. the work of Paul Turán).

The statement you propose is stronger than the famous [Density Hypothesis](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Density_hypothesis) (which is also implied by the Lindelöf Hypothesis) for the Riemann zeta function. This hypothesis would imply the above statement with $1/2$ in place of $7/12$.

Answer (score 5):

If the number were finite, one would get a drastic improvement of the error term in the prime number theorem as one direct consequence.

Recall that RH gives, and indeed is equivalent to,
$$
\pi(x)- \operatorname{Li}(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \epsilon})
$$
for every $\epsilon>0$.
More generally, one has that if $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros in the complex halfplane $H_{\sigma} =\{z \colon \Re(z)> \sigma\}$ then 
$$
\pi(x)- \operatorname{Li}(x) = O(x^{\sigma + \epsilon})
$$
for every $\epsilon>0$.
Now if the number of zeros were finite it would in particular follow that there is some $\sigma_0<1$ such that $H_{\sigma_0}$ contains no zeros of $\zeta$ (recall that all zeros are known to have real part less than $1$ and if their number is finite take the max of the real parts), and we had
$$
\pi(x)- \operatorname{Li}(x) = O(x^{\sigma_0 + \epsilon})
$$
for every $\epsilon >0$.

This would be a lot better than the current error term of the form $O(x \exp(-c (\log x)^{3/5}) )$.